# Create SCCM Package through Powershell "New-CMPackage -FromDefinition" Method

Tags: sccm, configurationmanager

I am trying to create new sccm packages using sms file, but I am unable to create package. Getting below error. Could someone please suggest?

Package definition "LAB TEST Create Package" is already compiled and available in SCCM console. We are able to create manually through console.

PS PSY:> New-CMPackage -FromDefinition -PackageDefinitionName "LAB TEST Create Package" -sourcefiletype AlwaysObtainSourceFile -sourcefolderpath $Source1 -sourcefolderpathtype UncNetworkPath
WARNING: The parameter 'SourceFolderPathType' has been deprecated and may be removed in a future release.
WARNING: Input an existing package definition name.
New-CMPackage : Validation of input parameters failed. Cannot continue.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-CMPackage -FromDefinition -PackageDefinitionName "SG Create Package" -source ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Confi...wPackageCommand:NewPackageCommand) [New-CMPackage], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValidationFailed,Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Cmdlets.AppModel.Commands.NewPackageCommand

Comment: Afaik normally if you specify an unc path it has to be available only to the sccmserver, however I read that for the PS cmdlets it has also to be available to the user that runs the cmdlet because of the validation of the inputs (see here: https://talhaqamar.com/2017/02/02/import-cmapplication-validation-of-input-parameters-failed-cannot-continue/). Is that the case?

Comment: @Syberdoor , I am trying to create package through "Create Package from definition" method using PowerShell. I don't understand what's wrong with the command line. I could able to create manually. The command line I have used as below.

New-CMPackage -FromDefinition -PackageDefinitionName "LAB TEST Create Package" -sourcefiletype AlwaysObtainSourceFile -sourcefolderpath $Source1 -sourcefolderpathtype UncNetworkPath

Comment: Yeah my question was is the path $Source1 available to the user you run the script with? Normally if you do this in the console the path must only be available to the server not your user but with PS it has to be reachable for both. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, That source file is accessible for everyone. And we are using same source path for manual package creation.